# unable to maintain attendence record

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to make an attendence system with daily attendence filled and submited by some authorised person

what i was unable to sort out was the attendence at the back end in the database??

Can u help me and explain the working on backend attendence record as i want to fill attendence on regular basic then what should i do how do i maintain create and update tables with attendence record

this is what i want

```
name batch attendence_date_1 attendence_date_1 attendence_date_1
```

is this a right way if no then what is the most prefered way to do this ???

Comment: show what have you tried? table scripts?

Comment: i havent created a table but i want to know the concept before creating a table retrieving and inserting data is easy but i am confused about creating the structure of table..

Comment: http://www.programmingforums.org/thread28254.html

Comment: You need to create an employee table and then attendance table with foreign key referring to the employee table attendance table will include EmployeeId, Date, LogIn Time, Logout Time

Comment: ok thanks let me check

Comment: yeah thanks for the foreign key concept i didnt thought for using foreign key

Comment: Naveen the concept in the url  is same thanks dude

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, **show us specifically what you did** so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.